# RNN LSTM Forecasting Python

Tags: python, validation, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I created an RNN-LSTM Forecasting for a time series.
the time series has 498 rows.
the seq size is 10 with 1 output.
Training 80% and Test 20%.

Model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTUJJ.png)

Training and validation loss:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPtOj.png)

Visualisation Forecast and orignal data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Lrp.png)

And I predict a few days:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvd8d.png)

I m really new by forecasting with NN. I seems quite good.

But I m not sure if there could be overfitting.

Can you evaluate the results? Im not sure if this is a good prediction.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edit it and provide the code for the model.